# Wordpress + react serverless on same domain

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, .htaccess, aws-amplify, dreamhost

I'd like to get some advice on hosting solutions for my personal projects written with react and one WordPress website. Assuming I have domain named example.com:

1. Show WordPress on the root level, so when someone opens example.com, WordPress renders its homepage.
2. React website named First is available at example.com/first.
3. React website Second is available at example.com/second.

React websites should be able to handle their own cookies. Is this configuration possible at all or should I just use subdomains?

I currently use DreamHost for WordPress, for react websites I intend to use AWS amplify.

The most suiting thing for this I've found so far is a reverse proxy. After a few hours, the best I could achieve with AWS amplify is that it renders reacts as root website and opens WordPress at the subdirectory like /blog, so opposite of what I want to get.

DreamHost shared hosting doesn't support reverse proxies at all.

Should I move WordPress to a VPS or a managed hosting where I have full control over .htaccess and ability to use reverse proxies? Will the server with reverse proxy be required to be powerful enough to handle traffic for all websites or routing with proxies isn't a heavy task?